# What is process of extract things from browser request when I use strtok_r(buff, " \r\n", &saveptr);?

Tags: c, strtok

Let's say I have read browser request in line and save it to buff. I want to extract some information like method, url, versoin from this buff. So I want to use strtok_r to split it.

Suppose the request is "GET http://******** HTTP/1.1". ********* is a website link. I set a certain token, and use the following piece of code:

```
cmd = strtok_r(buf1, token, &saveptr);
strcpy(url, strtok_r(NULL, token, &saveptr));
version = strtok_r(NULL, token, &saveptr);
```

Firstly, if I set token as " ". Then, I will get cmd="GET", url = "http://********". However, there is no " " behind VERSION. So this might cause problem.

Secondly, if I set token as "\r\n". Then, I will get cmd="GET http://******** HTTP/1.1", which is wrong.

So the right way may set the token as " \r\n". But I am not sure the process. Can anyone explain why this works???

Comment: Is there something *specific* in the function [documentation of `strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) that you do *not* understand as it relates to this question ? Btw. who said you had to use the *same* token list in each of your posted calls ?

Comment: try to set token as " \r\n" (add a blank char)

Comment: If I get your question you can use multiple delimiters `strtok(str," /");` Now you have space as well as / as delimiters.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, you are right. I set different tokens later, and they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to mention here.

1. You can pass an array of more than one delimiters to `strtok()`/ `strtok_r()`. It will consider *each* element in the delimiter array while parsing for tokens. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) [*emphasis mine*]

> The delim argument specifies a **set of bytes** that delimit the tokens in the parsed string.

and

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter.

2. `strcpy(url, strtok_r(NULL, token, &saveptr));` this is a very dangerious way to write code. If `strtok()` fails and returns NULL, think of the *horror*. The best way to do so is collect the return value of `strtok()` in another variable and after NULL check, use that variable for `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and advice. Inspiring. I have changed the second line to a "normal" way.

Answer (score 1):

strtok (and family) works by eliminating all the characters from the first string that happen to appear in the second (individual characters, not sequences) and gives you a pointer of the first string that happens **not** to have any of its characters present on the second string.  It's historically used in the shell **sh(1)** where it uses the contents of the `IFS` environment variable to divide the input string and construct the `argv` array of strings to pass to the program to be **exec(2)**.

By the way, the algorithm used by **strtok(3)** and cousings is not adecuate to parse HTTP input, as you'll need to do parsing in several passes (one, using line delimiters to divide input buffer in line boundaries, and at least a second to divide line into parameter ---with a space as the second parameter)

To do parsing of http protocol is better to develop a specific parser o to scan things using language parsing techniques.  See **flex(1)** or **bison(1)** for help on this kind of utilities, standard in unix systems for a long time.